# XPCServices not updating the code

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan, launchd

I create project for os x application with xpcservices that run by loginItems. that's mean the service is founded in the app in the path:`{APP_NAME}.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems` 
and who is responsible for run the service is the the main app:

```
NSXPCConnection *connection = [[NSXPCConnection alloc] initWithLoginItemName:@"{SERVICE_NAME}.app" error:&error];
```

I used the class :NSXPCConnection+LoginItem.h from apple's docs example :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AppSandboxLoginItemXPCDemo/Listings/iDecide_NSXPCConnection_LoginItem_h.html

**Q:**
Why when I update the service code (even just logs) it's not changed?

**you should know:**

I deleted all the files that related to  this projects and service 
( I don't used LaunchAgents or LaunchDaemons folders)

I did remove the service by: `launchctl remove {SERVICE_LABLE}`

I used the Console App for seeing the difference between the version that I'm running

I even bought "cleanMyMac3.app" and did restart and still I run from Xcode the app and still show logs from previous version.

I searched file on the system that related to the service name, and I find few folders that created and I deleted them:

1. ~/Library/Group Containers/{SERVICE_NAME}
2. ~/Library/Containers/{SERVICE_NAME}
3. ~/Library/Caches/{SERVICE_NAME}
4. ~/Library/Saved Application State/{SERVICE_NAME}

**I'm not work sandbox**

Answer (score 0):

Do you reference the service (XPC service) properly?

i.e. (as per Apples Example)

```
`NSXPCConnection *connection = [[NSXPCConnection alloc] initWithLoginItemName:@"XYZABC1234.com.example.iDecideHelper.app" error:&error];`
```

Also as this example is pretty old, if you traverse the XPC requirements you'll notice that some changes need to be made:

1. Both the containing project (the iOS or OSX App) and the XPC service App ned to be sandboxed
2. Ideally, the XPC service should be named as: com.theMainApp.identifier.com.whateverServiceName.

So in the Apple example you've listed IDecideHelpers identifier would be:  `com.example.iDecide.WhateverServiceName`. iDecide (the main app) would be `com.example.iDecide`

Comment: I don't work with sandbox, and it's works when I changed the identifier like u said, but after awhile it still doesn't work..

Comment: Then the only other ways are with the xpc_main  api (Cxx based API) and the other is the documented under the Daemons programming guide... NSHipster (just had a quick look for quick answers) as a pretty comprehensive explanation of the Api's and their uses.http://nshipster.com/inter-process-communication/ <-- that's the link to the mach_port examples they have. Other than that, the Apple code should be sufficient. And as of 2.1 I've been writing XPC services (and XPCConnection Services) in swift (with some header help). Works fine :)